# Understanding pattern matching and the pipe operator

Tags: elixir

I'm having a hard time understanding the following code snippet:

```
Comeonin.Argon2.add_hash("hello123") |> Comeonin.Argon2.check_pass("hello123")
```

which outputs:

```
{:ok,
 %{
   password: nil,
   password_hash: "$argon2i$v=19$m=65536,t=6,p=1$thCv1TGdiLszGx+bRugcqQ$EH8PpUqpCGTevihslOdSRPWS6+UlQJwv2pMOvwBJUS4"
 }}
```

I want to understand 2 things here:

1. the order of the arguments passed to the 2nd function when using |>, is it always just passed as the 1st argument to the function? **What if it needs to be passed as the 2nd argument to the function?**
2. how to pattern match and deconstruct the return values

So running the 1st function I see this:

```
Comeonin.Argon2.add_hash("hello123")

%{
  password: nil,
  password_hash: "$argon2i$v=19$m=65536,t=6,p=1$GCmClx6W8PyzKjvh3UcKYQ$d3IMfhiEULCmMBuMF7eyBYgkPrXCBQdqQNOJNGr/3qI"
}
```

So it is returning a map.
How can I pattern match against this?

Why doesn't this work?

```
{a, b} = Comeonin.Argon2.add_hash("hello123")
```

Or if I wanted to ignore the 1st key:

```
{_, b} = Comeonin.Argon2.add_hash("hello123")
```

For pattern matching I tried this:

```
case Comeonin.Argon2.add_hash("hello123") do
 {password, password_hash} -> ...

end
```

But I think once I understand how to deconstruct the pattern matching will be the same?

Comment: **NB** you are mixing up tuples `{...}` and maps `%{...}`. The latter is key-value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the order of the arguments passed to the 2nd function when using `|>`, is it always just passed as the 1st argument to the function? **What if it needs to be passed as the 2nd argument to the function?**

Yes, it is always passed as the first argument. If you need to pass it as the 2nd argument, you don’t use pipe.

---

> how to pattern match and deconstruct the return values

```
result =
  "hello123"
  |> Comeonin.Argon2.add_hash()
  |> Comeonin.Argon2.check_pass("hello123")
```

To deconstruct and raise if the response is not expected

```
{:ok, %{password: password, password_hash: password_hash}} = result
```

To handle whatever response is  possible:

```
case result do
  {:ok, %{password: password, password_hash: password_hash}} -> ...
  _ -> :error
end
```

To pattern match and return any successful response:

```
case result do
  {:ok, %{} = password_map} -> password_map
  _ -> :error
end
```